# What is the difference between didMove(to view: SKView) and didMoveToView(view: SKView)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

As in the title, what is the difference between didMove(to view: SKView) and didMoveToView(view: SKView)?

I understand that didMoveToView is the method and that view is of type SKView in the older(?) version. I don't understand the deal with 'to view: SKView' being passed to the didMove method. Are 'to' and 'view' separate variables? Is 'to' part of 'didMove'? What is going on?

EDIT: I understand that they both accomplish the same thing - but why is 'to' in the area that parameters normally go? Is there a benefit to this? It seems to be unnecessary complication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is only in the syntax.

The new **Swift 3** syntax is `didMove(to view: SKView)`

In Swift:

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter
>   name.The argument label is used when calling the function; each
>   argument is written in the function call with its argument label
>   before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the
>   function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their
>   argument label.

```
func someFunction(argumentLabel parameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, parameterName refers to the argument value
    // for that parameter.
}
```

So , the `to` in the swift 3 version **is only the argument label**.

---

Probably you have also seen function where there is no need to insert the parameterName.

If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that parameter.

```
func someFunction(_ firstParameterName: Int, secondParameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, firstParameterName and secondParameterName
    // refer to the argument values for the first and second parameters.
}
someFunction(1, secondParameterName: 2)
```

Hope it helps to better understand these modifications: you can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

Comment: Thanks for this info.  That explains the difference in the function parameter labelling.  However, these functions also have different names.  Does that mean that one has been deprecated in favour of the other?

Comment: If you install Xcode 8 and use Swift 3, the current syntax is didMove(to view: SKView), so the other is actually wrong, not deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing!

`didMove(to view: SKView)` is Swift 3 syntax.

`didMoveToView(view: SKView)` is Swift 2.x syntax.

FYI many many other parameters and method namings changed from Swift 2 to Swift 3. A very good list of changes can be found [here](https://buildingvts.com/a-mostly-comprehensive-list-of-swift-3-0-and-2-3-changes-193b904bb5b1#.so9btl3rj)

### usage

It's debated but to most people the Swift 3 syntax is *more* readable since you do `didMove(to: xyzView)` while the Swift 2.x syntax is *less* readable when you do `didMoveToView(xyzView)`

Comment: Except when you hit the cases that hide the parameter label lol. Then if you do not name your variables correctly, it becomes less readable

Comment: This is good info.  How about the difference in function names?  Has one been deprecated?

Comment: @SonofaBeach if I understand you correctly: if you are Swift 3, then Swift 2 syntax is deprecated, if you are in Swift 2, then there is no Swift 3 syntax

Comment: Sorry if I sound ignorant (yet to switch from Objective-C to Swift).  I'm not referring to the syntax, but to the function itself.  The two functions have completely different names (ie, "didMove" and "didMoveToView").  This is not just syntax, but a completely different function name (due to the different syntax making the function naming standard different, no doubt).  Is one of these functions only available when using Swift 2 and the only the other available when using Swift 3?

Comment: *Is one of these functions only available when using Swift 2 and the only the other available when using Swift 3?* Yes they are exclusive to a Swift version